# Github authentication failed with user www-data

Tags: php, git, nginx, github, ssh

I'm setting up a hook between Github and my server, which can auto pull new commits when the script triggered by Github requests.

It's all setting finished, like ssh-keys, git origin. I can pull a new commit from my private repo hosted on Github by running `git pull origin master`. It's works fine with the shell.

But when I write that command into a `deploy.php` file, it can be triggered by Github, but with error message.

```
Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

After that, I run a command `whoami` through the php file, it returns user `www-data`.

Actually, I generate a key for `www-data` user, and put them in `/var/www/.ssh`, also copied `id_rsa.pub` and pasted it to Github, still have an authentication failure.

- nginx
- All files are set to belong `www-data:www-data`
- I have add `www-data`'s public key to the repo's deploy keys.

The `deploy.php` command

```
shell_exec("cd /var/www/html/tinfo/; git pull origin master 2>&1;");
```

My question is

1. How to create a key for `www-data`?
2. Is `www-data`'s `.ssh` directory `/var/www/.ssh`?
3. If I'm not wrong, why does github refuse my connection? I guess it's related about the user `www-data` who execute `deploy.php` file and run commands through PHP.
4. When talk to Github server, does `www-data` not sent its private key to the server?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think this should be a bash script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem solved with adding GitHub to known hosts according to Benyi's comment.

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> /var/www/.ssh/known_hosts
```

You should specify ssh key firstly. After that, you should do git tasks what you want.

1-) Ssh keys are not user specific. So you can create rsa key pair everywhere. Public key should be copied to github. Private key should be placed on your host.

2-) In linux environment, default `.ssh` folder path is under the users home directory. If you do not specify user's home folder, it should be in `/home/www-data/.ssh`. If you can not access this folder you should specify your ssh key that have written in my example.

3-) In linux environment, `deploy.php` runned by user who executing `nginx` process. Commonly `apache2` and `nginx` processes executed by `www-data user`.

4-) You should specify your ssh key path for sending this key file for authorization when you talk with github server.

Comment: Thank you for helpful opinions. Finally I found that  1. Generate a key for `www-data` by `$ sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa`  2. Upload key to Github 3. Generate `known_hosts` for `www-data` by `$ ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /var/www/.ssh/known_hosts` 4. chmod all files belonging to `www-data:www-data`.

Comment: Good to hear that.